# Laravel 5 model field explode to link to other models

Tags: laravel, models, explode

I have a field in my `master` table with a field called `data` which has ids stored like `0005,0006,0010` which are keys for records to be extracted from another table called `table1`. It's kinda like a belongsToMany except it's not broken into individual records, but same functionality.

I'm wondering how to explode `master.data` field off the comma and return the records for `table1` in the model. In this example, I'm wondering how to return `table1.* where table1.id=0005 or 0006 or 0010`.

If I was to call it, it would be something like auth()->user()->master()->table1() with 5,6,10 in that array

Comment: Pete it would be appreciated if you could improve your question, the problem is not clear enough

Comment: yes, i think it should be clearer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by `whereIn` method. First you have to fetch the row from `master` table. I assume the row id `5` which has the column named `data` containing value `0005,00006,0010`

```
$master = DB::table('master')->where('id',5)->select('data')->get();
// it returns "0005,0006,0010"

$users = DB::table('table1')->whereIn('id',[$master])->get();
// it will return all rows which has id 0005, 0006 and 0010
```

> **Remember:** The second argument of `whereIn` must be an array.

Comment: I think it works better like this for me since I have to do it multiple times from one record. I had this solution before, but was hoping laravel could do it faster. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is storing serialized list of IDs (a little like JSON does) in a `data` column. And if I understand you want to be able with Eloquent/MySQL to search in that. This is not possible that's why you need a pivot table with a `belongsToMany()` relation. Now you can select the related models when doing query on master.

If I missunderstood and you are just storing IDs in your `data` column and that does not need to be queried then you can create an accessor that explode that :

```
public function getDataAttribute()
{
    return explode(",", $this->data);
}
```